# Dart multiple "inheritance"

Tags: dart

Is there a way to have some sort of multiple inheritance in Dart? I can't use Mixins because the "base" class must then inherit from Object (in my case the "base" class needs to extend ChangeNotifier). Something like protocol oriented programming?

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BaseModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _busy = false;
  bool get busy => _busy;

  void setBusy(bool value) {
    _busy = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Because `BaseModel extends ChangeNotifier`, one can't say:

`class A with BaseModel` - wrong

You can mostly say `class A extends BaseModel`, but I am trying to avoid inheritance.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by mixins requiring your base class to inherit from `Object`. (All Dart object inherit from `Object` anyway.)The `mixin` class *itself* can't derive from anything else, but there is no such restriction on the class *using* the mixin.  Alternatively, if you just want a class to support multiple interfaces/protocols, your class can use [`implements` for any number of types](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#implicit-interfaces).

Comment: @jamesdlin sorry for the confusion. The base class, whose api I want to make available to other classes, extends `ChangeNotifier`, therefore cannot be used as a mixin since it's not declared as extending `Object`. I can't say `class A with BaseClass`

Comment: And I don't want to reimplement the API that was implemented already by the base class. I need the base class API to be shared. I can do this with composition of course, but I was wondering about any other way.

Comment: I think it would be way easier to help you if you showed us a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro - I've added an example, thanks